# Bootstrap4 Navigation Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The navigation bar is working fine in the large-md screen sizes. but in the xs-s screen size, the navigation button won't expand. Can anyone help me with this ?

I have included the required scripts in the HTML file as well.
I am using Bootstrap4 with Node.js
Following is the HTML code:

Ristorante Con Fusion

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm bg-primary fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="index.html">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsable-nav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<header class="jumbotron"> <!-- sets apart this part of the page from others -->
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row row-header">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking creations will tickle your culinary senses!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="container content">
    <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 order-sm-last col-md-3">
            <h3>Our Lipsmacking Culinary Creations</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm order-sm-first col-md">
            <h2>Uthappizza</h2>
            <p>A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <h3>This Month's Promotions</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm col-md">
            <h2>Weekend Grand Buffet</h2>
            <p>Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per person </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-content last-item align-items-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 order-sm-last col-md-3">
            <h3>Meet our Culinary Specialists</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm order-sm-first col-md">
            <h2>Alberto Somayya</h2>
            <h4>Executive Chef</h4>
            <p>Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience having worked closely with whos-who in the culinary world, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian fusion experiences. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">             
            <div class="col-4 offset-1 col-sm-2">
                <h5>Links</h5>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7 col-sm-5">
                <h5>Our Address</h5>
                <address>
                  121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                  Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                  HONG KONG<br>
                  Tel.: +852 1234 5678<br>
                  Fax: +852 8765 4321<br>
                  Email: <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
               </address>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 align-self-center">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="http://google.com/+">Google+</a><br class="hidden-custom">
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=">Facebook</a><br class="hidden-custom">
                    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/">LinkedIn</a><br class="hidden-custom">
                    <a href="http://twitter.com/">Twitter</a><br class="hidden-custom">
                    <a href="http://youtube.com/">YouTube</a><br class="hidden-custom">
                    <a href="mailto:">Mail</a><br class="hidden-custom">
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row justify-content-center">             
            <div class="col-auto">
                <p>© Copyright 2018 Ristorante Con Fusion</p>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<!-- first jquery, then popper and then bootstrap.js files to work properly -->
<script src="node_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What bootstrap/jquery version do you use? It seems to work in my fiddle.

Comment: @arkhz I am using Bootstrap4 and jQuery version 1.9.1. It was a dependency installation with Bootstrap4. I am new to this so I am not able to figure out a solution.

Comment: Okey, do you get any error in the developer console? Since it seems to work for me. Is your Jquery mapped correctly? I get the same problem if I remove jquery.

Comment: I am getting the following errors:

1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
bootstrap.min.js:1
2. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Oh okey, do you have an umd directory "/dist/umd/" ? If thats the case, try use boostrap + popper from umd instead of dist.

Comment: No, I dont have that directory.

Comment: Okey, could you try to replace your popper with the following (normal error when there is wrong reference to popper):
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Its giving an error : Failed to load resource.

Comment: The only error now left is with the bootstrap.min.js as it shows it failed to load the specified resource. I have added popper from umd directory.

Comment: Okey, seems like the path you entered is incorrect. Verify that the path for jquery and bootstrap is correct. See if you can find the files in the given path inside the browser source tree. A working fiddle btw: https://jsfiddle.net/b3uhr4kj/1/

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved.

Comment: Great, I'll post an answer for this for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to use popper from correct directory.

Use:

"**/dist/umd/popper.min.js**" instead of "/dist/popper.min.js/".

Answer (score 0):

Just as @arkhz said the issue might be using popper from incorrect directory.
replace your popper import at bottom with this

```
<script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

if this doesn't work try pasting the code below, it might work

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ml-3">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html">
                        <i class="fa fa-info"></i> About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-list"></i> Menu</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contactus.html">
                        <i class="fa fa-address-card"></i> Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<header class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-header">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
                <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking
                    creations will tickle your culinary senses!</p>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
        <div class="col=12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <h3>Our Lipsmacking Culinary Creations</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm col-md">
            <h2>Uthappizza</h2>
            <p>A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine
                cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
        <div class="col=12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 order-sm-last">
            <h3>This Month's Promotions</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm col-md order-sm-first">
            <h2>Weekend Grand Buffet</h2>
            <p>Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six
                main entrees and five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per
                person </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <h3>Meet our Culinary Specialists</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm col-md">
            <h2>Alberto Somayya</h2>
            <h4>Executive Chef</h4>
            <p>Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience having worked closely with whos-who
                in the culinary world, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian fusion experiences. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 offset-1 col-sm-2">
                <h5>Links</h5>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="aboutus.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Menu</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contactus.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7 col-sm-4">
                <h5>Our Address</h5>
                <address>
                    121, Clear Water Bay Road
                    <br> Clear Water Bay, Kowloon
                    <br> HONG KONG
                    <br> <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i>: +852 1234 5678
                    <br> <i class="fa fa-fax fa-lg"></i>: +852 8765 4321
                    <br> <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
                    <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
                </address>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-4 align-self-center">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google" href="http://google.com/+"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id="><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-linkedin" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google" href="http://youtube.com/"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon bg-light" href="mailto:"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-auto">
                <p>&copy; Copyright 2018 Ristorante Con Fusion</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Better use CDN Link for bootstrap4 to avoid this kind if issues
example: It is there in w3schools :

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).